# Awesomium custom surface scroll

Tags: textures, sdl2, pixel, awesomium

I have a custom [Awesomium::Surface](http://www.awesomium.com/docs/1_7_2/cpp_api/class_awesomium_1_1_surface.html) implementation, and I need to create a Scroll function for it. The function asks me to manually move some pixels of my texture by the indicated X and Y offset.

How can I move/access pixels inside a `SDL_Texture` since `SDL_LockTexture()` provide write-only pixels?